# Springboot with jersey configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to create a REst service (Jersey) application with Spring Boot but I'm unable to reach the REST class when I request the URL. My Spring Boot application class as below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({PersistenceConfig.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { 
    ServiceMarker.class,
    RepositoryMarker.class }
)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


  @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet(){
        ServletRegistrationBean register = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(),"/*");
        register.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
        return register;
    }
}
```

I tried to load the persistence xml using config class
My Persistence Class as below

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:database/leasingdb.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH = "hibernate.max_fetch_depth";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE = "hibernate.jdbc.batch_size";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String[] ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = {
        "in.test.leasing.admin.domainmodel.Users"};

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

     @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
     public DataSource dataSource() {
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
         dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
         dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
         dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
         return dataSource;
     }

     @Bean
     public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
         JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
         return transactionManager;
     }

    private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdaptor() {
         HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
         vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
         return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

         LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
         entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdaptor());
         entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
         entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);             
         entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaHibernateProperties());

         return entityManagerFactoryBean;
     }

     private Properties jpaHibernateProperties() {

         Properties properties = new Properties();

         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_MAX_FETCH_DEPTH));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_FETCH_SIZE));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_JDBC_BATCH_SIZE));
         properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

         properties.put(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");
         properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER, "false");      
         return properties;       
     }

}
```

jerseyConfig below

```java
public class JerseyInitialization extends ResourceConfig{

public JerseyInitialization(){
    this.packages("in.test.leasing.admin.api");

   }

}
```

Rest class

```java
@RestController
@Component
@Path("/Test")
public class Test {

@GET
public String getMessage()
{
    return "Hello";
}

}
```

Im getting 400 Bad Request with connection: closed

Comment: Did you miss out `@Component` for JerseyInitialization?

Comment: No I added these @Component in JerseyInitialization already